# How to map same entity to different databases and ignoring a column only for one DB in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two SQL Server databases, `DB1` and `DB2`.

I have only one code base pointing to both the databases. I'm using Entity Framework Core with a code-first approach to map classes to tables. Is there a way to ignore a specific column only for one database, and not for others?

If I ignore the column as below then it is not mapping for both the databases. Is there a way to map only if the column exists or else ignore rather than simply ignoring the column?

```
public class SampleConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Sample>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Sample> builder)
    {
        builder.Ignore(item => item.columnproperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd move this configuration from the EntityTypeConfiguration into the context class (OnModelCreating()), since there you can determine which DB you are targeting - probably by connection string, keep in mind you can't use the actual connection before the model is created.

Comment: I'd not recommend to hard code any values for that matter to ignore the column property in the configurations. Is there a way to ask entity framework core to look the DB it is being connected to and ignore the columns that doesn't have the properties or viceversa?

Comment: EF has to build the model of the database before it can connect. If you plan to alter the model afterwards, you'll have to use a different context for connection checking and look for the connection properties you are using to determine the DB. But I'd assume any such property would also be available in the used connection string, which doesnt require a DB connection to be established, and doesn't require information sharing across contexts.

Answer (score -2):

This may be the answer for your question.

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ignore-method

Create function to detect which DB you use and use this function to do checking in Configure.

```
public class SampleConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Sample>
{
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Sample> builder)
{
    if (DB == "DB1")
        builder.Ignore(item => item.columnproperty);
}
```

}

Comment: This should be a comment instead. And avoid linking to external pages without providing context.

Comment: I provided code already. I added it before you commented. I was typing in mobile phone.

Comment: @Asherguru my question is more towards, how to ignore the column based on the Database with out hard coding it.

Comment: my answer is what you want. Create function to detect which DB you use and do checking to ignore column based on DB you use currently through DB detection function you created. Your "builder.Ignore(item => item.columnproperty);" is considered as hardcoded already.

Comment: Let's say for example if we have to add another DB for this entity structure we should go ahead and add the corresponding config in the class file, which will force us to build, test and so on for all the DBs we support. Instead my question is more towards ignoring the column based on the DB and thanks to point out that we don't need to specify ignore too, if that is the solution.